# How to post data to my server after successfull twitter authentication

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to implement twitter authentication on my website same as visitors comment on [aljazeera.com](http://aljazeera.com).
Currently i'm using twitteraouth library in Codeigniter framework and
it is working fine as i can see twitter data after successfull authentication.

What i want to do is to add functionality that users comment on a post should be stored on my server by their twitter user_id.

Comment: Read [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) what is wrong in your question.

Comment: I tried my best to explain my question in a better way and in my point of view everything is clear enough. @[Tpojka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/939630/tpojka)  Could you please point out what is exactly with my question?

Comment: Same way user logs in website, you should make check before posting comment. Without seeing specific part of code that bothers you, I can't tell more.